# Validation field date required

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to know how do I implement a validation in this situation, where I trigger the message to the user stating that the field should be populated?

```
try
{
    if (process == null)
        process = new Process ();   
    try
    {
        DateTime DateSep = DateTime.Parse (line.ItemArray [18] .ToString ());
        processInterested.DateSep = DateSep;
    }
    catch
    {
        logErro.Append ("The cell S" + (line ["index"]) + "must be filled witha date.");
        fileInvalidated = true;
    }
} 
catch (Exception error)
{
    fileInvalidated = true;
    logErro.Append (error.Message + "<br>");
}
```

Comment: Instead of try/catch on your DateTime parsing, why not just use `DateTime.TryParse()`?

Comment: the root `try/catch` is useless as long as your `new Process()` doesn't doing some logic that may throw an exception.

Comment: maccettura, 
I've never used it that way, what would it be like in my case? Strange because with .Parse it worked, now not anymore.

Comment: CodeNotFound, 
I use the Process () yes referent in other aspects, as I am working with the Date field inside the try I decided to shorten the code and quote only what I am having problem.

Comment: Would you have any examples or suggestions?

Comment: @user9789539 check out [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch92fbc1(v=vs.110).aspx).  Instead of throwing an exception it returns a boolean of whether it was successful or not

Comment: I want to know if there is a different way of doing a validation without having to follow this code naming that I posted? I tried something like: 
but I could not do something like that. DateTime dateSep;
...
if(dateSep == null) // <-- will never be 'true'
  ...

Comment: I needed to validate the Dates field that I have in the worksheet and not let the user save the data without the field being filled, the idea was to trigger this log to the user stating that he should fill that field.

Comment: The question here is very unclear. If you are asking how to display the validation message instead of logging it, you will need to tag a tech (e.g. web forms or MVC). If you are asking how to store null in a DateTime, you can't, but you can store it in a [nullable type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/nullable-types/) such as  `DateTime?` (a.k.a. `Nullable<DateTime>`).